# Interrelating two arrays

Tags: javascript, html

I want to pick a random verb from one `array` and display its adverb by selecting from another `array` using a button.

I want to solve the following two issues:

**Issue 1:**

How do I make the button clickable only for 5 times, and then display a message "Come tomorrow!", which I have hidden with `CSS`.

**Issue 2:**

How do I make the button clickable for an infinite number of times and keep showing the random words.

Here is my code:

```js
const EL_verb = document.querySelector("#verb");
const EL_adverb = document.querySelector("#adverb");
const EL_btn = document.querySelector("#btn");
const verbs = ["Slow", "Quick"];
const adverbs = ["Slowly", "Quickly"];

var i;
for (i = 0; i < verbs.length; i++) {
  var randomVerb = verbs[Math.floor(Math.random() * verbs.length)]; //index for a random verb
}

const displayWords = () => {
  EL_verb.innerHTML = randomVerb;
};

EL_btn.addEventListener("click", displayWords);
```

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  padding: 4px 16px 16px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

#msg {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h2><u>Random Verb and Adverb:</u></h2>
  <h3 id="msg">Come tomorrow!</h3>

    <p><b>Verb: </b><span id="verb"></span></p>
    <p><b>Adverb: </b><span id="adverb"></span></p>

    <button id="btn" type="button">RANDOM</button>
</div>
```

Comment: what does it mean to click button 5 times and click button infinite times. Are  there 2 buittons?

Comment: Explain this line "I want to pick a random verb from one array and display its adverb by selecting from another array using a button."

Comment: Anyway you understood the issue and solved. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to figure out an issue and update an answer.

```js
const txtVerb = document.querySelector("#verb");
const txtAdverb = document.querySelector("#adverb");
const lblMessage = document.querySelector("#msg");
const lblRandomIndex = document.querySelector("#randomIndex");
const btnRandom = document.querySelector("#btnRandom");

const arrVerbs = ["Slow", "Quick"];
const arrAdverbs = ["Slowly", "Quickly"];

/**
* Any of the below declaration consider as infinity.
*/
// const triggerLimit = Infinity;
// const triggerLimit = Math.pow(10, 1000);
const triggerLimit = 5;
let counter = 0;

/**
 * @description display random message
 */
const showRandomMesasge = () => {
  const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * arrVerbs.length);
  txtVerb.innerHTML = arrVerbs[randomIndex];
  txtAdverb.innerHTML = arrAdverbs[randomIndex];
  lblRandomIndex.innerHTML = randomIndex;
}

/**
 * @description display words
 */
const displayWords = () => {
  if (counter >= triggerLimit) {
    lblMessage.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    lblMessage.style.display = 'none';
    showRandomMesasge();
    counter++;
  }
};

btnRandom.addEventListener("click", displayWords);
```

```css
.wrapper {
  font-family: 'arial';
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  padding: 4px 16px 16px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

#msg {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h2><u>Random Verb and Adverb:</u></h2>
  <h3 id="msg">Come tomorrow!</h2>
    
    <p><b>Verb: </b><span id="verb"></span></p>
    <p><b>Adverb:</b><span id="adverb"></span></p>
    <p><b>Random index:</b><span id="randomIndex"></span></p>

    <button id="btnRandom" type="button">RANDOM</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
const EL_verb = document.querySelector("#verb");
const EL_adverb = document.querySelector("#adverb");
const EL_btn = document.querySelector("#btn");
const verbs = ["Slow", "Quick"];
const adverbs = ["Slowly", "Quickly"];

max = Infinity;
clicked = 0;
function getRandomIndex() {
    for (i = 0; i < verbs.length; i++) {
    var randomVerb = verbs[Math.floor(Math.random() * verbs.length)]; 
    }
    return verbs.indexOf(randomVerb);
}

const displayWords = () => {
    if (clicked < max) {
    idx = getRandomIndex()
    
    EL_verb.innerHTML = verbs[idx];
    EL_adverb.innerHTML = adverbs[idx];
    clicked++;
    } else {
     EL_verb.innerHTML = 'Come Tomorrow!';
    EL_adverb.innerHTML = 'Come Tomorrow!';
    }
    
};

EL_btn.addEventListener("click", displayWords);
```

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  padding: 4px 16px 16px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

#msg {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h2><u>Random Verb and Adverb:</u></h2>
  <h3 id="msg">Come tomorrow!</h3>

    <p><b>Verb: </b><span id="verb"></span></p>
    <p><b>Adverb: </b><span id="adverb"></span></p>

    <button id="btn" type="button">RANDOM</button>
</div>
```

Change the `max` to limit the number. Also please note that verbs and adverbs here should be of the same length and in the same order.

PS: I suggest you to follow the standard naming conventions. Take a look at [this](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_conventions.asp)